# Why does Gulp revert all my changes when restarting Angular server?

Tags: angular, gulp, angular-material, angular-material2

I have an Angular project with /dev and /dist directories.  I do all my development work in /dev.  However, whenever I need to restart the server I lose all my changes that I have made (index.html, controllers, etc.).  Therefore, the only solution right now is to try and keep the freshet backup copy and paste it back in when it happens.  Any ideas why this is happening?

gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var iife = require("gulp-iife");
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var Server = require('karma').Server;

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);

gulp.task('init', ['sass', 'bower', 'js', 'uglify-js', 'image', 'image-min', 'html', 'index']);

// Static Server + watching js/scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['init'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dev'
        }
    });

    /* If you use a proxy replace the previous code with the below script replacing 'yourlocal.dev' with your local proxy

        browserSync.init({
            proxy: 'yourlocal.dev'
        });

   */

    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['sass-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/images/*', ['image-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/**/*.html', ['html-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/js/**/*.js', ['js-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./bower_components/**/*.js', ['bower']);
});


gulp.task('index', function() {
    var target = gulp.src('./dev/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['./bower_components/**/*.js', './public/js/config/app.js', './public/js/factories/**/*.js', './public/js/services/**/*.js', './public/js/controllers/**/*.js', './public/js/filters/**/*.js', './public/js/directives/**/*.js', './bower_components/**/*.css', './public/css/**/*.css'], { read: false });

    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('image', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/images/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/public/images'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/public/images'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/public/css'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/public/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/public/js'))
});

gulp.task('bower', ['index', 'index:dist'], function() {
    return gulp.src(['./bower_components/**/*.min.js', './bower_components/**/*.min.css'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/bower_components'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/bower_components'));
});

gulp.task('image-watch', ['image', 'image-min'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

gulp.task('html-watch', ['html'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

gulp.task('sass-watch', ['sass', 'index', 'index:dist'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

gulp.task('js-watch', ['js', 'uglify-js', 'index', 'index:dist'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

//DIST:

gulp.task('image-min', function() {
    gulp.src(['./public/**/*.png', './public/**/*.jpg', './public/**/*.gif', './public/**/*.jpeg'])
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/public'));
});

gulp.task('uglify-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./public/js/config/app.js', './public/js/factories/**/*.js', './public/js/services/**/*.js', './public/js/controllers/**/*.js', './public/js/filters/**/*.js', './public/js/directives/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/min/'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/min/'));
});

gulp.task('index:dist', function() {
    var target = gulp.src('./dist/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['./bower_components/**/*.js', './public/js/min/anonymous.min.js', './bower_components/**/*.css', './public/css/**/*.css'], { read: false });

    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});

gulp.task('dist:iife', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/js/min/all.min.js')
        .pipe(iife())
        .pipe(rename('./js/min/anonymous.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/public'));
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['dist:package'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dist'
        }
    });

    /* If you use a proxy replace the previous code with the below script replacing 'yourlocal.dev' with your local proxy

        browserSync.init({
            proxy: 'yourlocal.dev'
        });

   */

    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['sass-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/images/*', ['image-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/**/*.html', ['html-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./public/js/**/*.js', ['js-watch']);

    gulp.watch('./bower_components/**/*.js', ['bower']);
});

gulp.task('dist:package', ['sass', 'bower', 'uglify-js', 'image', 'image-min', 'html', 'dist:iife', 'index:dist']);


//TDD

/* Run test once and exit */

gulp.task('spec', function(done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});

/* Watch for file changes and re-run tests on each change */

gulp.task('serve:spec', function(done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
    }, done).start();
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your gulp file?

Comment: may be you are editing the generated files from gulp and not the source wich gulp copy, try share you gulp file.

Comment: I included the gulp file.  I am very new to Gulp so I was not aware of this file or the need to edit it.  I am sure that is where my problem is residing.  Is my problem because browserSync.init({server: { baseDir: './dev'} }); newly initializes the .dev directory when calling gulp serve command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at your `gulp config` and seams like after you run `gulp serve` you have to `code/modify` in your `public` so when anything is getting changed in `public` folder it it getting copied in to `dev` and `dist` folders.

Your `browserSync` is looking in to `dev` folder when you running `gulp serve` so it is always sync with your `public` folder. Basically `dev` and `dist` is always automatically generated based on whats in `public`.

`dist` always has all assets mimified and ready to deploy on a server.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it makes sense now.  I thought that I was supposed to do all my development work in public folder under dev.  I see now that there is a top level public folder as well.